# Скачивание файла(мп3, zip) из приложения Android на телефон, без доступа в интернет

Tags: java, android

Моя цель сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог по нажатию кнопки скачать файл из самого приложения. Не из интернета:) В идеале в папку Download. Я уже довольно долго пытаюсь решить эту проблему, так как я новичек в разработке приложений. Ниже код, который я пока что cмог создать:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
Button button;
private View clicked;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void onClick(View view) {
    clicked = view;
    {gotoact1(clicked); }
}


private   void gotoact1(View view)
{
    switch (view.getId()) {

        case
                R.id.button:
            saveResourceToFile();

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

public void saveResourceToFile() {
    InputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    try {
        in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.net);
        String downloadsDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
        String filename = "net.mp3";
        fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(downloadsDirectoryPath + "/" + filename));

        final byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            fout.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "DownloadOne!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "DownloadTwo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (fout != null) {
            try {
                fout.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

При нажатии на кнопку срабатывает Toast с надписью "DownloadTwo". В логах видно, что сработало исключение FileNotFoundException. Может быть кто либо сталкивался с такой проблемой или знает что можно попробовать сделать? Сам файл находится в папке res/raw и называется net.mp3

Comment: Неверно указан путь к папке

Comment: к папке с файлом или папку куда нужно скачать?(

Comment: попробуйте файл так создать File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File file = new File(path, "net.mp3"); плюс должно быть разрешение на запись (не уверен нужно ли сюда)

Comment: Жалко, но результат тот же(

Comment: Ответ нашел, нужно было добавить разрешение, всем спасибо)